# Sort object not working

Tags: powershell, wmi

Does anyone know why the `Sort-Object` is not working in this code?

```
gwmi win32_computersystem -comp $Computer.FullDomainName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
    select Caption,Username | Sort Caption
```

Comment: works fine for me

Comment: What makes you believe it doesn't work?

Comment: the result i get prog313 then pc203 then laptop044 then pc247

Comment: Im guessing you are running this in a loop. you would need to send all the results first to variable and then when that is done display the variable and have it sort that. if you run it like this in a loop you only get single results

Comment: To be able to properly help we would require the rest of the script, or atleast the part where the loop starts or where u define the var $computer

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] including actual and desired output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to expand on @Kage's comment and guess an answer.

```
gwmi win32_computersystem -comp $Computer.FullDomainName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
select Caption,Username | Sort Caption
```

This query is getting the Caption of a single computer, so when you sort it there's nothing happening. `"laptop244" | sort` does nothing. I guess your code looks (roughly) like this:

```
foreach ($Computer in (Get-AdComputer -Filter *))
{
  gwmi win32_computersystem -comp $Computer.FullDomainName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
  select Caption,Username | Sort Caption
}
```

But it needs to look like this:

```
# Loop over the computers and gather all the results into one array

$ComputerDetails = foreach ($Computer in (Get-AdComputer -Filter *))
{
  gwmi win32_computersystem -comp $Computer.FullDomainName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
  select Caption,Username
}

# Sort all the details in that array in one go
$ComputerDetails | Sort Caption
```

Comment: yeah that was my problem. Thanks